# Find the Domain of $\sqrt{2-\sqrt p}$

Tags: calculus

What is the domain of $\sqrt{2-\sqrt p}$

I set $\sqrt{p}$ greater or equal to zero; however, I am confused how the overlap works. Do I set 2 - greater or equal to zero also? How should I approach questions like these?

Comment: What is $\surd p$, that can be *set* to some value? Then number 2 is 2. You can't set it to be something else.

Comment: I am asked to find the domain. Thus the first radical is supposed to be set to greater or equal to zero. After that I am confused as what to do.

Comment: can you see that $p$ cannot be too large? once you observe that see how large it can get i.e. what is the boundary value? how far can $p$ be pushed?

Answer (score 3):

For the expression to be defined you need two things
$$
p\geq 0 \quad \text{and}\quad 2 -\sqrt{p} \geq 0.
$$
You need this because you are taking the square root of both these two expressions.

If you solve the second inequality, you get $p \leq 2$ or $p \leq 4$. So you have in all $p\geq 0 $ and $p\leq 4$.

Comment: Can you show me step by step? I am confused how you got $p\geq 0 \quad \text{and}\quad 2 -\sqrt{p} \geq 0$

Comment: @Cetshwayo: I got those two inequalities becuase you are taking the square root of both in your original expression. You can only do that if both are greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: I find your answer confusing and not helpful. I am in my fist semester of calculus. I am looking to understand the "overlap" concept. That is can you convince me your answer is correct visually.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to define a set $M$ such that for every $p\in M$ you expression is well defined. For a square radical to be defined you should require that the expression under it is greater than $0$. Therefore we require that $p\geq 0$. Now, knowing this, you require $2-\sqrt p\geq 0\Rightarrow 2\geq \sqrt p$. Since these are positive numbers you can square this inequality and you get that $4\geq p$. Taking the two conditions, you get that $0\leq p\leq 4$, therefore $M=[0,4]$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, you are right, I shall edit.

Comment: Your explanation uses math jargon I am unfamiliar with. As a novice calculus student, it would be more helpful if you would visually show me the steps that you went about attaining your answer.

Comment: @Cetshwayo The domain of a function is the set for which the function exists (for example $1/x$ does not exist in $x=0$ so we shall say the function $1/x$ is not defined in $x=0$.) Radicals are not defined over negative numbers because when you square any number you get a positive one (2^2=(-2)^2=4), therefore you cannot have the radical of a negative number. For the other part, when you have an inequality between two positive numbers say $0\leq a\leq b\Rightarrow b+a\geq 0, b-a\geq 0\Rightarrow (b+a)(b-a)>0\Rightarrow b^2+ab-ab+a^2\geq 0\Rightarrow b^2-a^2\geq 0\Rightarrow a^2\leq b^2$.

Comment: @Cetshwayo If you have $p\geq 0 \& 4\geq p$, it follows that $0\leq p\leq 4$, therefore $p\in[0,4]$.

Answer (score 0):

when you are asked to find the domain of a function, it is meant you find the biggest set of values that the function can operate on. the two operations to watch out for are: not dividing by zero and not taking the square root of a negative number.

it looks like here you are being trained on not taking the square root of a negative number. your function $f(p) = \sqrt{2 - \sqrt p}$ has two square roots. as in any algebraic evaluation , you start with the innermost one. here that is $\sqrt p.$ so remembering not to take the square root of negative number, $p$ must be nonnegative. that is written as $p \ge 0.$

now we look at the outer square root. you want to take the square root of $2 - \sqrt p.$  that means you can only have $2 - \sqrt p \ge 0.$ the boundary value of $p = 4$ gives you $2 - \sqrt 4 = 0.$ now you can test points on either side and discover that only $p \le 4$ guarantees $2 - \sqrt p \ge 0.$

putting the two constraints together the $p$ must satisfy $$0 \le p \le 4.$$